# reduce or improve big O complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

What wording would be correct to say "I can ***reduce*** the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n)" but reduce in algorithm analysis means you can cast one problem in terms of another for which there exist a known solution. Therefore, I think is more correct to say "I can ***improve*** the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n)". Right?

Separate from this if I improve the complexity from, e.g., O(n^2) to O(n) would this be a correct way to say it? I improved the complexity by "one order of complexity"? or by "one or several degrees of complexity"?

Comment: There is no such thing as "one order of complexity", because complexity is not just a number. What would you call change from O(n^2) to O(n log^3 n)?

Comment: Instead of "one order of complexity", try "a factor of n" (similarly, "a log factor").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question in your first paragraph either *reduce* or *improve* is acceptable.  If you hold fast to the idea that *reduce* necessarily implies recasting a problem then stick to *improve*.  Personally I don't see that *reduce* does necessarily imply recasting a problem, but I'm often wrong in these matters.

As to your the question in your second paragraph, I don't think that the phrase *one order of complexity* is well-defined and you should, therefore, avoid it.